# Jersey RESTful deployment on Tomcat 6

Tags: web-services, rest, jersey, tomcat6

I am using the following setup to deploy a REST webservice on Tomcat 6 and it works:

```
<web-app>  
  <servlet>  
    <servlet-name>RestServlet</servlet-name>  
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>  
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>  
  </servlet>  
  <servlet-mapping>  
    <servlet-name>RestServlet</servlet-name>  
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>  
  </servlet-mapping>  
</web-app>
```

With the above setup, Tomcat scans `WEB-INF/classes` and `WEB-INF/lib` folders for the resources.

I then changed it to the following setup to use `Application` sub-class:

```
<web-app>  
  <servlet>  
    <servlet-name>RestServlet</servlet-name>  
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>  
    <init-param>  
           <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>  
            <param-value>test.MyApplication</param-value>  
    </init-param>  
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>  
  </servlet>  
  <servlet-mapping>  
    <servlet-name>RestServlet</servlet-name>  
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>  
  </servlet-mapping>  
</web-app>
```

where `test.MyApplication` is the sub-class of `Application` returning the resource class:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
  public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
    Set<Class<?>> s = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
    s.add(MyResource.class);
    return s;
  }
}
```

But still the server scans `WEB-INF/classes` and `WEB-INF/lib` for the resources.

What am I missing? Does the server still scan `WEB-INF` when `Application` subclass is set in the `web.xml`?

Answer (score 1):

> Does the server still scan WEB-INF when Application subclass is set in the web.xml?

No it doesn't. [The documentation explains](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/latest/jersey/com/sun/jersey/spi/container/servlet/ServletContainer.html) that scanning the path is done if no resource configuration related initialization parameters (like `javax.ws.rs.Application`) are present.

You should see what's in your server logs. When Jersey initializes it logs what it's doing and for a classpath scan it prints something like:

> INFO: Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the Web app resource paths:
>   
> /WEB-INF/lib
>   
> /WEB-INF/classes

When you provide an `Application` class it prints this instead:

> INFO: Instantiated the Application class test.MyApplication

You should make sure that the proper `web.xml` file is deployed when the server starts. Maybe you still have the old version deployed.